# Dependence of lens power on the refractive index of the medium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction, lenses

How does the power of a lens depend on the refractive index of the surrounding medium?

Comment: What do you mean by "how.." ? Do you mean "why" ? Or are you trying to ask "what do they mean when they say that the power of the lens depends on..." ?

Comment: Yes , i am asking 'how' the lens power depends on the refractive index of the medium? Is, there any mathematical formula to describe it ?

Comment: The refractive index of a material (lens) is directly proportional to its density. If you put the lens in water for example, or some medium with a density close to that of the lens, it will lose its strength. Light gets "bent" when it passes from one medium to another with a very different density (refractive index). So the power of the lens depends on the difference between its density and that of the medium. I don't know the mathematical formula 

Answer (score 1):

You want the *lens maker's equation* $$\frac{1}{f}=(n_\mathrm{lens}-n_\mathrm{medium})\left(\frac{1}{R_1}-\frac{1}{R_2}\right)$$ where $R_1$ and $R_2$ are the radii of curvature of the two sides of the lens.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the *difference* between the refractive index of the lens and that of the surrounding medium: the bigger the difference, the stronger the lens. If those are the same, the lens is no longer a lens. If the refractive index of the lens is greater than that of the surrounding medium, then it is a lens and a convex lens like that will bend light to a focal point. On the other hand, if the refractive index of the lens is less that that of the surroundings, then a convex lens like that will disperse a light beam outwards.

Comment: Is there mathematical equation of lens power formula which depend on the refractive index of the medium ?

Answer (score 0):

To find the power of a lens in a medium, we can use the following formulas.

Power of the lens is equal to the refractive index of any medium other than air which is divided by its focal length.

$$ P = \frac{\mu}{f} \tag{1} \label{1} $$